# scrollable after holding?

Tags: android-layout, android

I use scrollview in a fragment, scrollview contains one `ListView`

My code:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroller"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/menu_list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/menu_listview_item_selector"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="11dp"
            android:paddingTop="0dp" />
</ScrollView>
```

I have a problem with scrolling of the content. ListView is programmatically filled up with items consists from RelativeLayout and TextView. These items are active and calls other action. When I try to scroll these items, it is possible only after holding finger on some item in listview.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a `ListView` contains a `ScrollView` of it's own so you don't have to put it inside another one. Simply delete the `ScrollView`.

Comment: But I want to scroll fragment. ListView must stay in ScrollView.

Comment: please explain exactly the wanted behavior. what you saying doesn't make sense - if the user scrolls over the ListView, should it scroll the list or the whole fragment?

Comment: I added the screen, it explains my desired behaviour.

Comment: I solved it, I deleted `ScrollView` but moreover I added  XML attribute `android:scrollbars="vertical` to `ListView`.